# Is there a lightweight, embeddable, key/value database? (something like diet couchdb)

Tags: database, rest, couchdb, embedded-database, key-value

I was wondering if there was a lightweight, embeddable, key/value database out there.

Something like a lightweight Couchdb (RESTful, key/value, etc) where you just send it the key and it responds with appropriate values.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused.... RESTful *and* embeddable?

Comment: Is 'portable application' implied in the specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the [Related Projects](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Related_Projects) page of the CouchDB wiki, under "Alternatives" they mention some similar projects:

- [Feather DB](http://fourspaces.com/blog/2008/4/11/FeatherDB_Java_JSON_Document_database)<sup>*</sup> CouchDB clone in java.
- [StrokeDB](http://www.strokedb.com/)<sup>*</sup> A CouchDB-like database written in Ruby to make embedding into Ruby apps easier.
- [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) A high-performance, open source, schema-free document-oriented database.

And of course [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) which has already been mentioned.

There's also [neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) which is a "graph database" for java.

Of course, part of the power of CouchDB and some of the others is not just being able to store key/value pairs, but the high capacity, replication, and in particular views, which are basically the way of running queries over your documents.

If you just needed a simple key/value datastore that you can embed into your program, that doesn't have to hold gigs of data, the venerable [GDBM](http://www.vivtek.com/gdbm/) might suit your needs.

A little hard to answer without knowing a bit more about your needs (programming language, concurrency requirements, data volumes and such).

<sup>*</sup> Web site does not appear to be working at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 5):

Would TinyCDB be suitable?

http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/tinycdb.html

**Introduction**

TinyCDB is a very fast and simple package for creating and reading constant data bases, a data structure introduced by Dan J. Bernstein in his cdb package. It may be used to speed up searches in a sequence of (key,value) pairs with very big number of records. Example usage is indexing a big list of users - where a search will require linear reading of a large /etc/passwd file, and for many other tasks. It's usage/API is similar to ones found in BerkeleyDB, gdbm and traditional *nix dbm/ndbm libraries, and is compatible in great extent to cdb-0.75 package by Dan Bernstein.

CDB is a constant database, that is, it cannot be updated at a runtime, only rebuilt. Rebuilding is atomic operation and is very fast - much faster than of many other similar packages. Once created, CDB may be queried, and a query takes very little time to complete.

Comment: Didn't know about TinyCDB, but I would kill for a CDB clone that doesn't have the 4GB size restriction.

Comment: If you're keen, modify the source to remove the restriction.

Comment: 2.5 million records tonight on my MBP took 0.081s to find a random record with cdbget.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, embeddable key/value database ? That's pretty much [BDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB)

Answer (score 3):

The OS filesystem is a lightweight key/value database.  Keys are filenames and values are data in the files.

The word "embeddable" has an odd meaning if it's to be RESTful, so I don't really understand your requirements; but if all you need is storage and retrieval, why not use the FS?

Comment: At no point did the OP say that he *only* needed storage and retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

For what platform? [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/) is a lightweight, embeddable, associative database engine for a variety of scripting environments (Java, Ruby, Perl, Lua, et al.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/perst/) -- it's licensed GPLv2 and/or proprietary depending on your needs. I've never used it but I hear that it's good. It's an application-embedded key-value store database under active development with ports to a number of popular frameworks and languages.