# CouchDB on Windows?

Tags: windows, couchdb, shared-hosting

I started exploring CouchDB and I am interested in following:

1. Is there or will there be a Windows install?
2. If there is, is there a shared hosting provider that offers CouchDB?
3. Not knowing much about it, can it be somehow embedded in my application or bin deployed (don't laugh).

Comment: Wow, an hour without an answer.

Comment: Windows Installer available through CouchDB wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Windows_binary_installer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a Windows version now, available on [CouchIO](http://www.couch.io/get) (http://www.couch.io/get) blog.

1. Download & Unzip
2. Double-Click bin\couchdb
3. Relax!
4. Visit http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils

Comment: These are old versions.
Please vote up my answer below with a link to the current windows build.  At the time of the post CouchDB is a 1.0.1 which is much more feature rich the the versions listed in these first two comments and much easier to install.

Comment: please update to couchbase + proper edition (couchbase single server?)

Answer (score 17):

1. The most reliable source is [the CouchDB download page](https://couchdb.apache.org/#download)
2. There are several places offering CouchDb hosting. Besides [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/), you can use most Infrastructure-as-a-Service parties like Google, AWS, etc.
3. This question was asked (and answered) elsewhere on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161766/is-there-a-lightweight-embeddable-key-value-database-something-like-diet-couc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516226/embedded-couchdb).

Comment: To add to your very good answer, Cloudant offers a hosted version of CouchDB (currently in beta) - https://cloudant.com/  I just got my account, so I can't give it a full review yet, but I know the company has several of the Couch committers.

Answer (score 3):

There's been a fully compatible Windows build of CouchDB shortly after every source release, since the initial 1.0.0 release over 18 months ago. You can get this directly from the Apache CouchDB mirrors http://couchdb.apache.org/ now.

NB the embedded test suite is actually for developer testing; due to subtle timing constraints not all tests will pass first time round on every machine. In the next release of CouchDB, the tests will be done outside the browser which will be both simpler and more robust.

Please up-vote this so we have the right information to hand.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, there is a Windows download available at https://couchdb.apache.org/ .

Comment: I replaced the dead link. I didn't try this product since it moved out of Git Hub, so I don't have an opinion on the Apache version. dch's answer is more complete than mine anyway.